# App Crashing after change phone language and relaunch from background

Tags: android, localization, multilingual, android-anr-dialog

I am developing an android app and facing some strange issue. while App is in background and user change phone language and relaunch app from background then app force stop.

Strange thing is that app crashes only when i change language from english to french but while change from french to english or some other language it will work without any crashing.  below are error log -

> Process: com.myapp, PID: 17745
>                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
>                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1515)
>                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:638)
>                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:621)
>                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:162)
>                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
>                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
>                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
>                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
>                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                                    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
>                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
>                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
>                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
>                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a **bug** that has appeared from the support features added for the nested fragments.

Basically, the FragmentManager ends up with a broken internal state when it is detached from the activity.

Try this on your Fragment :

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    try {
        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you change the language of the device the new instances of the fragments created, and the app tries to find the new instances.

You need to store your fragments' instance in a List to avoid this type Exception.

If you provide your code where the fragments are added, then it will be more clear .